# What do この場合のできるというのは and ということ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

The sentence: この場合のできるというのは、努力を重ねれば成果が出るということ、そしてその継続ができるということ。

The sentence that came before the one shown above is this: 傲慢なことを言うなら、自分ができる人間なのだと早々に知った。

It looks like ということ is only quoting the two phrases "努力を重ねれば成果が出る" and "そしてその継続ができる".

About この場合のできる, I know the meaning of both "場合" and "できる", but I don't understand this set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of this sentence is:

> この場合の[A]というのは、[B]ということ、そして[C]ということ(だ)。
> [A] in this case means that [B] and that [C].

Adding brackets might make it easier to parse it:

> この場合の「できる」というのは、「努力を重ねれば成果が出る」ということ、そして「その継続ができる」ということ。
>
> "(The word)「できる」 in this case means 「努力を重ねれば成果が出る」 and 「その継続ができる」." / "By saying 「できる」 in this case, I mean 「努力を重ねれば成果が出る」 and 「その継続ができる」."

It refers to the use of 「できる」 in 自分が**できる**人間なのだと... in the previous sentence.